# Search by name in non latin characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do a search using,

`Product.order(:name).where("name like ?", params[:term])`

Where :term is in non latin characters (Hebrew).
Both my application and my database are set to UTF-8
application.rb

`config.encoding = "utf-8"`

database

`utf8_unicode_ci`

and the specific name I'm searching is in the database, but the search comes out empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table you're searching? If there are only a handful, that could be your issue.

Comment: well for testing there is only one row and I search for exactly it but it won't find it :-(

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that will work. Usually, when there is only 1-4 rows of data, not a whole lot will be returned on search. Try adding about 10 rows of *unique* data. Then try searching. Let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add % of my own in the `params[:term:]`
So now it is

`Product.order(:name).where("name like ?", params[:term]+"%")`

I am not sure if this the best way to achieve what I wanted but it works nonetheless ...